# How to get a table with the values of a given raster layer aggregated by a second raster layer in grass?

Tags: grass-gis, raster-calculator

Let's say in grass I have a raster layer "regionId" (integer) and a raster layer "forestArea", where I store the ha of forest within the pixel (float).

How can I get a table summing up the forest area by region ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zonal statistics for rasters in GRASS are done with the `r.univar` module. It includes a parameter 'zone' to specify a categorical map, then a table of stats is produced with a row for each category in that map.

So you would do something like:

```
g.region -p raster=regionId
r.univar input=forestArea zones=regionId separator=comma
```

See: [r.univar man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.univar.html) for full details.